# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in a counting loop in Java

Tags: java, string, stringindexoutofbounds

I have to write a code for class using Java in which the number of occurrences of the letter E is counted and printed out (both cases included). This is what I have.

```
String sVerse = "As we enter our centennial year we are still young ";

System.out.println(sVerse);

int len3 = sVerse.length();
int countE = 0;

for (int d = 0; d <= len3; d++){
    char e = sVerse.charAt(d);
    d = d + 1;

    if (e == 'e' || e == 'E')
    {
        countE = countE + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        countE = countE;
    }
}

System.out.println(countE);
```

The code runs, and the string prints, but after the string prints I get this error:

```
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1258
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Unit4plus.main(Unit4plus.java:125)
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details about how to make your code as presentable as possible - you can delete all those backticks. But then please present a [mcve] (ideally with conventional formatting).

Comment: But fundamentally, the problem is your use of `<=` in the loop condition...

Comment: remove d=d+1; from your loop as it's already being incremented

Comment: My guess is that your string contains 1258 and thus the last index is 1258. Have a look at `d<=len3` and think about what might happen if `d == len3`.

Comment: First, you should use < and not <=. charAt(size) will throw an exception by definition. Second, d++ and d=d+1 are redundant. keep only one.
Third, countE=countE does nothing, you don't need it.

Comment: Btw, if you don't need the index of the characters you might want to loop using foreach: `for( char c : sVerse.toCharArray()) { /* check c and count here */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You're increasing `d` inside the loop, which you shouldn't - just let the `for` loop do it's thing. Also, you should terminate the loop with `<`, not `<=`:

```
int countE = 0;
for (int d = 0; d < len3; d++) {
    char e=sVerse.charAt(d);

    if (e=='e' || e=='E') {
        countE++;
    }
}
```

But frankly, you could just stream the characters in the string for a much more elegant solution:

```
long countE = sVerse.chars().filter(c -> c == 'e' || c == 'E').count();
```

Comment: Play to your audience. It's clearly a beginner's assignment. The goal is probably to learn loops, conditional statements and other simple concepts. Recommending streams is at best unhelpful and at worst needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the first loop should be :

`d < len3`

Since length starts at 1 but index of characters in your string are 0 based.

Moreover, your statement d=d+1 in the for loop is useless and makes you iterate 2 by 2 since you already increment it in the for loop with

```
d++
```

Comment: What does `length starts at 1` means? With an empty String, you can get a length of 0.

Comment: With the example he posted, the value of his length is at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the condition for the loop since the length is +1 of the maximum index.You also increase the value of the variable "d" two times, one in the definition of the "for" loop, and the other is inside it. Try replace it with this code:

```
        String sVerse = "As we enter our centennial year we are still young";
        int len3 = sVerse.length();
        int countE = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d < len3; d++) {
            char e = sVerse.charAt(d);
            if (e == 'e' || e == 'E')
                countE++;
        }
        System.out.println(countE);
```