# I want to print the number of vowels, consonants, spaces, digits and special characters in the string entered by user

Tags: java

I need to print no. of vowels, consonants, spaces, digits and special characters in the string entered by user.

I am getting below error after running the program.

Input: Enter the word to count Vowels and Alphabets in it

java language version 15#

```
Output: 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 25
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at CountAlphabetsInWord.main(CountAlphabetsInWord.java:11)
```

````
public class CountAlphabetsInWord {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the word to count Vowels and Alphabets in it");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        int vowels = 0, consonants = 0, spaces = 0, digits = 0, specialCharacters = 0;
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++){
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            
            //check if any char is a, e, i, o ,u
            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'){
                vowels++;
            }
            else if(ch >=  '0' && ch <= '9'){
                consonants++;
            }
            else if(ch == ' '){
                spaces++;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                digits++;
            }
            else
                specialCharacters++;
        }
        System.out.println("Vowels: " + vowels);
        System.out.println("Consonants: " + consonants);
        System.out.println("Digits: " + digits);
        System.out.println("WhiteSpaces: " + spaces);
        System.out.println("Special Characters: " + specialCharacters);
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in a counting loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597279/stringindexoutofboundsexception-in-a-counting-loop-in-java)  Also, `consonants` count digits while `digits` count letters which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index `word.length()` is beyond the range of characters in `word`. Remember, it’s zero-indexed, so the range of characters is 0 to word.length - 1.

You just need to tweak your for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
```

Comment: Thanks for the Support, Your support works and program ran successfully with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an enhanced for loop so you don't have to worry about index out of bound errors, and for similar reasons utilize the inbuilt `Character` methods:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class AnalyzeStringInput {
    private static final Set<Character> VOWELS = Set.of('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string:");
        String string = scanner.nextLine();
        int vowels = 0, consonants = 0, spaces = 0, digits = 0, specialCharacters = 0;
        for (Character ch : string.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                if (VOWELS.contains(ch)) {
                    vowels++;
                } else {
                    consonants++;
                }
            } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch)) {
                spaces++;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                digits++;
            } else {
                specialCharacters++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Vowels: " + vowels);
        System.out.println("Consonants: " + consonants);
        System.out.println("Spaces: " + spaces);
        System.out.println("Digits: " + digits);
        System.out.println("Special Characters (anything else): " + specialCharacters);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter a string:
AbcDeF gHi JkLmnO 1234%  ~!56&*()

Vowels: 4
Consonants: 11
Spaces: 5
Digits: 6
Special Characters (anything else): 7
```

Answer (score 0):

use "i<word.length()" in for loop

Comment: Thanks for the help. it worked and my program gave expected output.